# Ajax send image within data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send some data by Ajax and this data may contain an image.

I **don't have any forms**, so I can't submit by the traditional way.

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/bmp" id="addProduct_image">
```

Whenever the user changes the file I get that value.

```
var files;

$(document).on('change', '#addProduct_image', function(e){
    prepareUpload(e);
});

function prepareUpload(event){
  files = event.target.files;
}
```

When the OK button is pressed I call an ajax function.

```
$(document).on('click', '#addProduct_OK', function(e){
    var img = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        img.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'responses/product.php?type=productAdd',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {title: $("#addProduct_title").val(), description: $("#addProduct_description").val(), 
               image: img, status: $("#addProduct_status").val()
              },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm currently receiving the error on chrome console

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

in the ajax line. I'm to far away from how to send an image by ajax with other data also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sent the FormData as the data for the ajax request, so the additional params also has to be appended to the fomdata

```
$(document).on('click', '#addProduct_OK', function (e) {
    var img = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function (key, value) {
        img.append(key, value);
    });
    img.append('title', $("#addProduct_title").val());
    img.append('description', $("#addProduct_description").val());
    img.append('status', $("#addProduct_status").val());

    $.ajax({
        url: 'responses/product.php?type=productAdd',
        type: 'POST',
        data: img,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There's only one thing missing in that code which is this two lines: `contentType: false,
processData: false`, otherwise it won't work. If you could edit your answer so I can accept it. Thank you.